# Client to Server sending string message c++

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client

I have a server and a client and I am attempting to send a message from the client to the server as a string. I successfully do this once but when I attempt to send another string I get the error: `client: connect error :Transport endpoint is already connected`

----- How to Compile -----

```
    g++ server.cpp -std=c++11 -o server.x -lpthread
    g++ client.cpp -std=c++11 -o client.x
```

----- How to execute -----

```
    ./server.x
    ./client.x <IP Address>
```

After execution of both files, the following options will appear:

---------- Options ----------

server - send a command to the server
exit   - exit program

If you type 'server', the following options will be:

-----Server Command Options:-----

m      -   send message to server

server.cpp

```
int main()  {
  int sockid, newsd;
  struct sockaddr_in my_addr, client_addr;
  socklen_t clilen = sizeof(client_addr);
  thread cmd;

  cout << "Server creating socket.\n";
  if( (sockid = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0) {
    cout << "Socket Error.\n";
    exit(0);
  }

  cout << "Server binding my local socket.\n";
  bzero((char *) &my_addr,sizeof(my_addr));
  my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  my_addr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT_ID);
  my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
  if( bind(sockid ,(struct sockaddr *) &my_addr,sizeof(my_addr)) < 0 ) {
    cout <<  "Bind error.\n";
    exit(0);
  }
  cout << "Server starting listen.\n";
  if( listen(sockid,5) < 0 ) {
    cout << "Listen error.\n";
    exit(0);
  }
  cout << "Server running...listening for connections.\n";

    for( ; ; ) {
    cout << "Server starting accept.\n";

    cout << "newd: " << newsd << endl;
    cout << "sockid: " << sockid << endl;
    cout << "client_addr: " << &client_addr << endl;
    cout << "clilen: " << clilen << endl;

    if ((newsd = accept(sockid ,(struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &clilen)) < 0) {
      perror( "Failed to accept." );
      exit(0);
    }
    cout << "newsd: " << newsd << endl;
    cout << "Server return from accept, socket for this ftp: "<< newsd << endl;

    //    close(sockid);   /* child shouldn't do an accept */

    thread cmd ( receiveCommand, newsd );
    //cmd.detach();
    //cmd.join();

    //    close (newsd);
    //    exit(0);         /* child all done with work */
  }
  //  cmd.join();
  /* Parent continues below here */
  close(newsd);    /* parent all done with client, only child */
  close(sockid);
  return 0;

}

void receiveCommand(int newsd)
{
  string cmd;
  int msg_ok,fail,req,tmp;
  char command[MAXLINE], commandSize = 0;

  req = 0;
  if((readn(newsd,(char *)&req,sizeof(req))) < 0) {
    perror( "Read error" );
    exit(0);
  }

  req = ntohs(req);
  cout << "Client request code is: " << req << endl;
  if (req!=REQUESTCOMMAND) {
    cout << "Unsupported operation. goodbye\n";
    /* reply to client: command not OK  (code: 150) */
    msg_ok = COMMANDNOTSUPPORTED;
    msg_ok = htons(msg_ok);

    if((writen(newsd,(char *)&msg_ok,sizeof(msg_ok))) < 0 ) {
      perror( "Write error." );
      exit(0);
    }
    exit(0);
  }

  /* reply to client: command OK  (code: 160) */
  msg_ok = COMMANDSUPPORTED;
  msg_ok = htons(msg_ok);
  if( writen(newsd,(char *)&msg_ok,sizeof(msg_ok))  < 0 ) {
    perror( "Write error.");
    exit(0);
  }

  fail = COMMANDOK;
  if( (commandSize = read(newsd,command,MAXLINE)) < 0 ) {
    perror("Command read error." );
    fail = BADCOMMAND ;
  }
  command[commandSize] = '\0';
  tmp = htons(fail);
  if( (writen(newsd,(char *)&tmp,sizeof(tmp))) < 0 ) {
    perror("Write error" );
    exit(0);
  }
  if(fail == BADCOMMAND) {
    cout << "Server cant do command.\n";
    close(newsd);
    exit(0);
  }
  cout << "Command is: " << command << endl;

  if( command == "gbye"){
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Client requested server to shutdown...\n";
    cout << "Goodbye.\n";
    exit( 0 );
  }
  else{
    cout << "Command TRANSFER COMPLETE on socket " << newsd << endl;
  }
  close(newsd);
}

/*
  To take care of the possibility of buffer limmits in the kernel for the
  socket being reached (which may cause read or write to return fewer characters
  than requested), we use the following two functions */

int readn(int sd,char *ptr,int size)
{
  int no_left,no_read;
  no_left = size;
  while (no_left > 0) {
    no_read = read(sd,ptr,no_left);
    if(no_read <0)  return(no_read);
    if (no_read == 0) break;
    no_left -= no_read;
    ptr += no_read;
  }
  return(size - no_left);
}

int writen(int sd,char *ptr,int size)
{         int no_left,no_written;
  no_left = size;
  while (no_left > 0) {
    no_written = write(sd,ptr,no_left);
    if(no_written <=0)  return(no_written);
    no_left -= no_written;
    ptr += no_written;
  }
  return(size - no_left);
}
```

client.cpp

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  int sockid, newsd, portNum, clientportNum, serverportNum;
  struct sockaddr_in my_addr, server_addr;

  if( argc != 2 ) {
    cout << "Error: Usage : IP-dotted-notation \n", argv[0];
    exit(0);
  }

  if( (sockid = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0 )  {
    cout << "Client Socket Error.\n";
    exit(0);
  }

  clientportNum = 8000;
  serverportNum = 8001;

  cout << "Client Binding My Local Socket\n";
  bzero((char *) &my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));
  my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  my_addr.sin_port = htons(clientportNum);

  if( bind(sockid ,(struct sockaddr *) &my_addr,sizeof(my_addr)) < 0 ){
    cout << "Client Bind Error.\n";
    exit(0);
  }

  cout << "Client Starting Connect\n";
  bzero((char *) &server_addr,sizeof(server_addr));
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(serverportNum);

  while( 1 ){
      string cmd_option;
      cout << endl;
      cout << "---------- Options ----------\n";
      cout << "server - send a command to the server\n";
      cout << "exit   - exit program\n";
      cout << endl;

      cout << "~: ";
      getline(cin, cmd_option);

      if( cmd_option == "server" ){
        // *****Error Here*****
        if( connect(sockid ,(struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0 ) {
          //cout << "Client Connect Error.\n";
          printf("client: connect  error :%s\n",  strerror( errno ));
          exit(0);
        }
        giveServerCommand(sockid);
      }
      else if( cmd_option == "exit" ){
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Exiting program...\n";
        cout << "Goodbye.\n";
        exit(0);
      }
      else{
        cout << "Invalid Command.\n";
      }
    }
}
void giveServerCommand(int sockid)
{

    string user_input;

    // User Interface
    cout << "\n-----Server Command Options:-----\n";
    cout << "m      -   send message to server\n";

    cout << "\n";

    cout << "~: ";
    getline(cin, user_input);

    if ( user_input == "m" ){

      string buffer;
      cout << "\nType a command to the server: ";
      getline( cin, buffer );
      cout << "You typed: " << buffer << endl;

      int getcommand,msg,msg_2,len;
      len = buffer.size();

      getcommand = htons(REQUESTCOMMAND);
      cout << "Client sending command request to server.\n";

      int n = 0;
      if( n = (writen(sockid,(char *)&getcommand,sizeof(getcommand))) < 0 ) {
        cout << "Client write error: " << n << endl;
        exit(0);
      }

      /* want for go-ahead from server */
      cout << "command: " << getcommand << endl;
      cout << "sockid: " << sockid << endl;
      cout << "msg: " << &msg << endl;
      cout << "msg size: " << sizeof(msg) << endl;

      msg = 0;
      if((readn(sockid,(char *)&msg,sizeof(msg)))< 0) {
        cout << "Client read error.\n";
        exit(0);
      }
      cout << "msg: " << msg << endl;
      msg = ntohs(msg);
      cout << "msg after ntohs: " << msg << endl;
      if (msg==COMMANDNOTSUPPORTED) {
        cout << "Server refused command. Goodbye...\n";
        cout << endl;
        exit(0);
      }
      else
        cout << "Server replied, command supported.\n";

      /* send command to server */
      cout << "Client sending command.\n";

      cout << "sockid: " << sockid << endl;
      cout << "buffer: " << buffer.c_str() << endl;
      cout << "len: " << len << endl;

      if ((writen(sockid, (char *) buffer.c_str(),len)) < 0) {
        cout << "Client write error.\n";
        exit(0);
      }
      /* see if server replied that command is OK */
      cout << "sockid: " << sockid << endl;
      cout << "msg2: " << &msg_2 << endl;
      cout << "msg2 size: " << sizeof(msg_2) << endl;

      msg_2 = 0;
      if (readn(sockid, (char *)&msg_2, sizeof(msg_2)) < 0) {
        cout << "Client read error: %s\n",  strerror( errno );
        exit(0);
      }

      cout << "msg2 before ntohs: " << msg_2 << endl;
      msg_2 = ntohs(msg_2);
      cout << "msg2 after ntohs: " << msg_2 << endl;

      if (msg_2 == BADCOMMAND) {
        cout << "Server reported bad command. Goodbye...\n";
        exit(0);
      }
      else
        cout << "Server replied, Command OK.\n";

      /*Command transfer ends. client terminates after closing all its sockets*/
      cout << "COMMAND TRANSFER COMPLETE\n";
    }
    else{
      cout << "\nInvalid Option.\n";
    }
}

int readn(int sd, char *ptr, int size)
{

  int no_left,no_read;

  cout << "-----Within readn function------" << endl;
  cout << "sd: " << sd << endl;
  cout << "char ptr: " << &ptr << endl;
  cout << "size: " << size << endl;

  no_left = size;
  while (no_left > 0) {
    no_read = read(sd,ptr,no_left);
    cout << "no_read: " << no_read << endl;
    if(no_read <0)  return(no_read);
    if (no_read == 0) break;
    no_left -= no_read;
    ptr += no_read;
  }
  cout << "size - no_left: " << size - no_left << endl;
  cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;
  return(size - no_left);
}

int writen(int sd,char *ptr,int size)
{
  /*
  cout << "-----Within writen function------" << endl;
  cout << "sd: " << sd << endl;
  cout << "char ptr: " << &ptr << endl;
  cout << "size: " << size << endl;
  */
  int no_left,no_written;
  no_left = size;
  while (no_left > 0) {
    no_written = write(sd,ptr,no_left);
    //cout << "no_written: " << no_written << endl;
    if(no_written <=0)  return(no_written);
    no_left -= no_written;
    ptr += no_written;
  }
  /*
  cout << "size - no_left: " << size - no_left << endl;
  cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;
  */
  return(size - no_left);
}
```

Error: `client: connect  error :Transport endpoint is already connected`

Comment: Are you running multiple clients or servers at a time on the same machine?

Comment: Just one client and one server on the same machine @NathanTuggy

Comment: Binding the client socket before connecting is not necessary and may be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your client code appears wrong - you're calling connect() in a while(true) loop without the need for it - once your client has connected, it doesn't need to do so again until after the connection is terminated and the socket is closed.